# Compatibilty between GPRS and LTE modules and networks

Tags: telecommunications

I summerized the question for ease as follows:

1. Lets say we have an LTE module under the coverage of an old base
   station like 2G with GPRS. Will the LTE module work?
2. Lets say we have a GPRS module under the coverage of a newer base
   station like 4G with LTE. Will the GPRS module work?

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say we have an LTE module under the coverage of an old base station like 2G with GPRS. Will the LTE module work?

If, and only if, it implements 2G hardware, a fallback on that, and if the network subscription you have with the network operator allows that.

> Lets say we have a GPRS module under the coverage of a newer base station like 4G with LTE. Will the GPRS module work?

No, quite obviously. If it "spoke" 4G, it wouldn't be a 2G modem, would it?

Answer (score 0):

These are completely different protocols, so the simple answer is "no."

The complex answer is that there are very few base stations that are LTE only and deployed in a place with no GSM or CDMA coverage, and there are very few LTE capable modems that do not also support older protocols as fallback.

Comment: The first point may not be all that true.  But regardless, not just protocol has to match, but also frequency assignment and willingness of the system to interact.  Some modems also require an explicit firmware mode switch.  All of which points to this being too broad and too much as usage question not specifically answerable.

Comment: But if I want to send data using a uC and a cellular data module, how can I know that the module will work under any base station? For instance  https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/rees52-small-gsm-gprs-sim900-for-arduino-uno-mega-20188859188.html they call it GPRS shield. But if I build something with this how can I be sure it would send data through any base station? What should I do to start with first?